# ProviderManifestToken '2008' is different from '2005' that was encountered earlier

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I'm working on ASP.NET 4 and with Visual Studio 2010. This project is using Entity Framework.

I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 (by mistake) and a colleague 2005.

I've accidentally clicke the "Update model from database" button and the DB (which is sql server 2005) took my 2008 db.

So, when my colleague tried to run the app in his computer, he got this error:

> Entities.Model.ssdl(2,86) : error
>   0169: All SSDL artifacts must target
>   the same provider. The
>   ProviderManifestToken '2008' is
>   different from '2005' that was
>   encountered earlier.

We know what it means, but we don't know how to make the app accept his model (which is sql server 2005) instead of mine (which is sql server 2008).

Comment: may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316422/using-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2005-and-date-time

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the problem described in this question only after I had updated the ProviderManifestToken in *one* of of two .edmx files in my project as described [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316422/using-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2005-and-date-time).  I got the "ProviderManifestToken is different than was encountered earlier" error because I had only updated *one* .edmx file in my project, and not *both* (or *all*) of them.

Answer (score 0):

just open .emmx file and change ProviderManifestToken from "2008" to "2005"