# What type to use for the time in Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime

I use MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and entity framework.
I need to write an article when created, what type to create a database and model?

I know that you want to use so datetime2, but I have this type of data in the database there.

I tried in model 'DateTime', in database type 'datetime'

end I have error

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

**anser:** I dont initilize field

Comment: WHat is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried in model 'DateTime', in database type 'datetime'

Comment: Are you creating the model by hand??? You should use DB First or Model first approaches (create DB -> inherit model or viceversa)

Comment: @JotaBe, and hands, and automatically change nothing

Comment: Make sure that you provide a value for the datetime field > January 1, 1753 or make it nullable in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Please, have a look at this post http://chyuck.com/Post/View/68

So there are two solutions:

1. In the edmx file change ProviderManifestToken value from 2008 to 2005. For CodeFirst look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815846/how-to-configure-providermanifesttoken-for-ef-codefirst-in-a-connection-string).
2. Use datetime2 in your DB. Probably it's a better solution.

P.S. it's not connected to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: You can use .NET type DateTime and sql type 'datetime'. Do you have any problems with this approach?

Comment: I don't have edmx and 'datetime2' in database

Comment: Do you use DB First or Model first approach?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815846/how-to-configure-providermanifesttoken-for-ef-codefirst-in-a-connection-string

Comment: @Сергій, I do not know what she can help me