# System.ArgumentException: The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have just uploaded a new version of code to my server and got this error bug that i cannot understand and don't know how to solve - I had no changes with datetime2 - I don't even have this word in my code syntax.
Do you know what that means?

An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details:

> InnerException: System.ArgumentException: The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(_SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>
> at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>
> at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior

Comment: Knowing nothing of ef, any chance you are calling add parameters with value  without specifying data type? Name of method approximate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2005 and date time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316422/using-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2005-and-date-time)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that Entity Framework 4 somehow got the idea to use  SQL Server 2008. The fix was to edit the .edmx file in an XML editor and set the `ProviderManifestToken="2005"` instead of 2008. (You need to rebuild.)