# Does SQL Server 2005 support datetime2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sqldatatypes, datetime2

I can't find in the official documentation if SQL Server 2005 supports the `datetime2` data type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently it does not. Here are the supported [data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

**EDIT:**

According to the following sources [datetime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) was introduced in SQL Server 2008.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manisblog/archive/2007/08/28/sql-server-2008-enhancements-in-date-and-time-data-types.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150018/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101508-1.aspx

Comment: It says "SQL Server 2008" in the header of your link?

Comment: @ahmd0 I updated the link. It does not support datetime2 based on data types listed.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Open your EDMX in a file editor (or “open with…” in Visual Studio and select XML Editor). 
At the top you will find the storage model and it has an attribute ProviderManifestToken.
This has should have the value 2008. Change that to 2005, recompile and everything works.

NOTE: You'll have to do this every time you update the model from database.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you encounter this problem:

> **The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2**

you can see the solution as following:

[Using SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2005 and date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316422/using-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2005-and-date-time/316506#316506)